# Cannot display files with names with special characters

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

There is an upload box where users upload the image of their document ids. The thing is that whoever implemented this upload box, did not program it to encode the filename if there is special characters in it. So now there are a bunch of uploaded files in the server with special characters such as

```
14592-Carte  d'identité-072616143337.pdf
```

So when they tried to visualize it in the browser, the link they have is:

```
<a href="https://www.fortadpays.com/upload/memdocs/14592-Carte  d'identité-072616143337.pdf">See File</a>
```

Which is not working. I tried to use `urlencode()` to encode the filename but it is still not working.

How can I display those files with special characters?

Do I have to change the filenames first of all those files uploaded with special characters, so for example:

```
14592-Carte  d'identité-072616143337.pdf
```

Will be changed to:

```
14592-Carte-didentite-072616143337.pdf
```

In order to be able to display in the browser? What function do I use?

Also, What function should I use to change the names of the filenames in the original upload box so it does not upload files with names with special characters anymore?

Comment: Why does `urlencode()` not work? It produces `14592-Carte++d%27identit%C3%A9-072616143337.pdf` from `14592-Carte  d'identité-072616143337.pdf`which is safe for urls.

Comment: I would have thought so but for some reason it does not display in the browser. Maybe a server restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_replace() function:

```
preg_replace('/[^\da-z]/i', '-', $string);
```

This will replace all non-alphanumeric characters to "-"

And you could use this function to rename uploaded files directly after upload